# How to get strptime to raise ArgumentError with garbage trailing characters

Tags: ruby, validation, parsing, date

We have to handle user specified date formats in our application. We decided to go with `Date.strptime` for parsing and validation, which works great, except for how it just ignores any garbage data entered. Here is an irb session demonstrating the issue

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.01 > require 'date'
 => true 
ree-1.8.7-2010.01 > d = Date.strptime '2001-01-01failfailfail', '%Y-%m-%d'
 => #<Date: 4903821/2,0,2299161> 
ree-1.8.7-2010.01 > d.to_s
 => "2001-01-01"
```

what we would like, is behavior more like this

```
ree-1.8.7-2010.01 > d = Date.strptime '2001failfailfail-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to pass the resulting date through `strftime` using the same format and compare to the original string.

i.e. `valid = Date.strptime(date_string, format).strftime(format) == date_string`

One limitation of this is that it wouldn't handle leading 0s in parts of the date e.g. if you wanted to accept 2010-6-1 but `strftime` returned 2010-06-01 you wouldn't have a match.

Also, I'm not sure if this is what you meant or not, but your second example `Date.strptime '2001failfailfail-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d'` does raise an `ArgumentError`. It seems like only trailing junk is ignored.

Comment: this is a really good idea. what i meant by the second block is that is the behavior i want from the first block

Answer (score 0):

one way is to define a new class which does the validation first.

```
require 'date'

class Mydate 

    def self.strptime(string)
        raise ArgumentError 'Fail' if  string !~ /^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/
        Date.strptime(string)
    end
end

d = Mydate.strptime '2001-01-01'
puts d

d2 = Mydate.strptime '2001-01-02xxxx'
puts d2
```

Another way would be to open up the Date class, alias the strptime method, write a new one to do the validation you require and then call the aliased one.

```
require 'date'

class Date

    class << self
        alias :orig_strptime :strptime
    end

    def self.strptime(string)
        puts "in new strptime"
        raise ArgumentError 'Fail' if  string !~ /^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/ 
        Date.orig_strptime(string) 
    end  
end

d = Date.strptime '2001-01-01'
puts d

d2 = Date.strptime '2001-01-02xxxx'
puts d2
```